# Angular Event Emitting to change material theme

Tags: angular-material, angular9

Please I want to change the theme of my app by selecting one of the colors showing the image.
I have the following components:

- Header Component (path: 'src/app/shared/components/header')
- Default Component (path: 'src/app/layouts/default')
  The image below is the Default Component containing the Header Component.

[image: Image showing theme colors to be selected for my angular app]

**header.component.html**

```
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleSideBar()">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <span>APP LOGO</span>

    <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="flex-end">
      <ul fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
        <li>
          <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="theme">
            <mat-icon>format_color_fill</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <mat-menu #theme="matMenu">
            <div class="btn-wrapper">
              <button mat-mini-fab class="btn btn-default" (click)="selectedTheme='default'"></button>
              <button mat-mini-fab class="btn btn-purple" (click)="selectedTheme='purple'"></button>
              <button mat-mini-fab class="btn btn-pink" (click)="selectedTheme='pink'"></button>
              <button mat-mini-fab class="btn btn-deep-orange" (click)="selectedTheme='deep-orange'"></button>
            </div>
          </mat-menu>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
            <mat-icon>person_outline</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item>
              <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
              Sign out
            </button>
          </mat-menu>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
    import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() toggleSideBarForMe: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() selectedTheme: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleSideBar(){
    this.toggleSideBarForMe.emit();
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.dispatchEvent(
        new Event('resize')
      );
    }, 300);
  }

}
```

**default.component.html**

```
    <div [ngClass]="selectedTheme">
  <app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="toggle()"></app-header>

  <mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer mode="side" [opened]="sideBarOpen">
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
  </mat-drawer-container>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

**default.component.ts**

```
 import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-default',
  templateUrl: './default.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./default.component.scss']
})
export class DefaultComponent implements OnInit {

  sideBarOpen = true;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggle(){
    this.sideBarOpen = !this.sideBarOpen;
  }
}
```

Here is my custom theme file: **custom-theme.scss**

```
    @import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$my-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent, $my-app-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme);

.alternate-teal-theme {
  $teal-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-teal);
  $teal-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-yellow);

  // The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
  $teal-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

  // Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
  $teal-app-theme: mat-light-theme($teal-app-primary, $teal-app-accent, $teal-app-warn);

  // Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
  // Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
  // that you are using.
  @include angular-material-theme($teal-app-theme);
}

.purple {
  $purple-primary: mat-palette($mat-purple);
  $purple-accent: mat-palette($mat-light-green);
  $purple-theme: mat-light-theme($purple-primary, $purple-accent);
  @include angular-material-theme($purple-theme);
}
.pink {
  $pink-primary: mat-palette($mat-pink);
  $pink-accent: mat-palette($mat-yellow);
  $pink-theme: mat-light-theme($pink-primary, $pink-accent);
  @include angular-material-theme($pink-theme);
}

.deep-orange {
  $deep-orange-primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
  $deep-orange-accent: mat-palette($mat-teal, A100);
  $deep-orange-theme: mat-light-theme($deep-orange-primary, $deep-orange-accent);
  @include angular-material-theme($deep-orange-theme);
}
```

*Please how do I make the selected theme to take effect on the app?*

Answer (score 0):

The content of `custom-theme.scss` file should be passed or imported into your `style.scss`. So that the theme affects the complete application you must declare the class css of the same in a div that encloses the html content of your boostrap component. And the error that I notice in your code is that in the file `header.component.ts`  the output of the selectedTheme is not emitting any event, you should declare it like this `@Output() selectedTheme: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();`, Here I leave you a working example of everything I just explained: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-event-emitting-to-change-material-theme)

Comment: Thank you so much! @Juan Pablo. My only challenge is that you implemented it using radio buttons but it was very helpful. I guess i have to change my implementation to using radio buttons.

Comment: No matter the implementation, if you use radio buttons, or buttons, or any other element, you would only have to assign the theme in the on click event of the element you choose.

Comment: Ok. Please how do I change the implementation to a button especially this part:
emitThemeSelected($event: MatRadioChange) {
    this.selectedTheme.emit($event.value);
  }
 and this part:
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="_selectedTheme" (change)="emitThemeSelected($event)">
          <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let theme of themes">
            <mat-radio-button [value]="theme.themeClass">{{theme.name}}</mat-radio-button>
          </button>
        </mat-radio-group>
in the navbar component you created in stackblitz. I would really appreciate if you help. Thanks.

Comment: Change (change)="emitThemeSelected($event) for (click)="functionInCompoent(valueTheme)"  in the element html and ready

Comment: Pablo Moreno Martin, Please help me do this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61575366/11535870

Comment: You can check it now I have made changes to the url. please check. @JUAN PABLO